# Castle Windsor 3 AOP Via Attributes

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, aop

I have been looking for some simple examples of how to best use Castle Windsor 3 and AOP but via attributes not by adding the interceptors in each components definition.

So is there a simple way to get a method with an attribute like so:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   [Log]
   public virtual void DoSomething() {...}
}
```

To call through to an interceptor like so:

```
public class SomeInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
   //... add the logger and write out method start, exception, finished info
}
```

Without having to specify the interceptor against the actual SomeClass configuration, like so:

```
someContainer.Register(Component.For<SomeClass>().ImplementedBy<SomeClass>()).Interceptors<SomeInterceptor>();
```

In most other DI frameworks I have used, you can setup AOP via rules for the methods being called or by targeting attributes. So hopefully that gives you some indication of what I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add a [ComponentModel construction contributor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx) that will inspect components as they get registered and add the interceptor to those that require it.